# WPF DataGrid only fills from constructor

Tags: c#, wpf

I feel like I'm missing something extremely small but I can't figure out what the issue is. I've extracted what I'm attempting to do (and the problem) inside a simple application.

In my **MainWindow.xaml** I have (just a datagrid and a button):

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinitions Height="auto"/>
    <RowDefinitions Height="auto"/>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Button Content="Click me" Click="Button_Click"/>
  <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding TableResult}" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

In my **MainWindow.xaml.cs** (the MainWindow constructor and the button event):

```
private MyViewModel myView;

public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  myView = new MyViewModel();
  DataContext = myView;
}

private void Button_Click(...) => myView.FillTable();
```

In my **MyViewModel.cs**:

```
class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private DataTable tableResult = new DataTable();
  public DataTable TableResult
  { 
    get => tableResult;
    set
    {
      if(tableResult == value)
        return;
      tableResult = value;
      NotifyPropertyChanged(); // The event handler works fine, I just didn't type it out
    }

  public MyViewModel()
  {
    FillTable();
  }

  public void FillTable()
  {
    TableResult.Clear();
    TableResult.Columns.Clear();
    TableResult.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "Color" });
    TableResult.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "Is it Cool?" });
    TableResult.Rows.Add(new object[]{ "Red", "Yes" });
    TableResult.Rows.Add(new object[]{ "Pink", "Absolutely not" });
  }
}
```

The problem lies in here somewhere (I think), where the `MyViewModel` class works fine but **only** if `FillTable()` is inside the constructor. Whenever I take `FillTable()` out of the constructor and try to call `FillTable()` by clicking the button, the table never appears.

Similarly, if I leave `FillTable()` inside the constructor the table generates just fine! However, if I click the button, table disappears completely and never regenerates.

Am I missing something? If I use this type of method with say, an `ObservableCollection` of `string`, it works fine. Thanks in advance if someone can point me to this mistake I'm making or what I'm not seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this

```
public void FillTable()
{
   var res = new DataTable();
   res.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "Color" });
   res.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "Is it Cool?" });
   res.Rows.Add(new object[]{ "Red", "Yes" });
   res.Rows.Add(new object[]{ "Pink", "Absolutely not" });
   TableResult = res;
}
```

I believe your issue is due to the fact that just MANIPULATING the TableResult DOES NOT call the set property at all, it would only get called if you assigned a new TableResult to the property.

Comment: No dice unfortunately. I wish I could share a screenshot of what's happening but basically do you see how I'm just adding two rows? Whenever I click the button, the DataGrid is actually _doing something_, it adds two rows, but they're literally just two empty rows (and no columns).

Comment: Update... Your alternative solution just worked.. I don't understand. Because I did your first approach prior to writing this post, but your second approach worked just fine. Why wouldn't it work if I NotifyPropertyChanged at the end of the function as opposed to the latter?

Comment: Manipulating an object reference does NOT call the property setter so NotifyPropertyChange never gets called in your code. 
Assigning a new object reference WOULD hit the setter and call the NotifyPropertyChange. You may have caught me mid edit with some of the code.

Comment: Yes, you're correct and that's what I'm saying (and I saw the edit after you made it, that's why I added the Update comment). I literally _did_  invoke the NotifyPropertyChanged  event at the end of FillTable and it didn't work at all. But setting a new DataTable object to the Property worked just fine. -- Nevertheless, the latter solution is working perfectly fine; thank you very much! Need to figure out why the former isn't working because it was the entire reason I made this post lol.

Comment: @Chris A Binding ignores the PropertyChanged event when the property value hasn't actually changed. Same TableResult instance, hence no change.

Comment: @Clemens Ohhh! So _that's_ the issue at hand here as to why the latter works and the former doesn't.. That makes complete sense now. This was puzzling me for a while, because I've used this approach several times working on some MVVM projects, but now that I think about it, the parts I've worked on, I never actually worked on a property that uses an instance of an object as opposed to just setting a new object/value to the property.. That clears things up for me; thanks a ton to both of you! =)

Comment: @Clemens Called it out, I forgot about it being a pure reference pointer check.